# dataframe from hive table to iterate through each element for some operation and write in df,rdd,list

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a `DF` with input data as below:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+--------+
| abc|2E2J2K2F|
| bcd|    2K3D|
+----+--------+
```

My expected expected output is:

```
+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+----+------+
| abc|    2E|
| abc|    2J|
| abc|    2K|
| abc|    2F|
| bcd|    2K|
| bcd|    3D|
+----+------+
+----+------+
```

Comment: |col1|col2|
 +----+--------+
 | abc|2E2J2K2F| 
 | bcd|        2K3D| 
+----+--------+
expected output
 +-----+-----+ 
| col1| col2|
 +----+------+
 | abc| 2E|
 | abc| 2J|
 | abc| 2K| 
| abc| 2F| 
| bcd| 2K| | bcd| 3D| 
+----+------+ +----+------+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use udf() for splitting the string and then explode it. Check this out:

```
scala>  val df = Seq(("abc","2E2J2K2F"),("bcd","2K3D")).toDF("col1","col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string]

scala> def split2(x:String):Array[String] = x.sliding(2,2).toArray
split2: (x: String)Array[String]

scala> val myudf_split2 = udf ( split2(_:String):Array[String] )
myudf_split2: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.withColumn("newcol",explode(myudf_split2('col2))).select("col1","newcol").show
+----+------+
|col1|newcol|
+----+------+
| abc|    2E|
| abc|    2J|
| abc|    2K|
| abc|    2F|
| bcd|    2K|
| bcd|    3D|
+----+------+


scala>
```

Update:

the split2() is just splitting the string by 2 bytes each and creating an array.
The explode functions duplicates the row based on the length of the array, giving each index value for all the rows.

```
scala> def split2(x:String):Array[String] = x.sliding(2,2).toArray
split2: (x: String)Array[String]

scala> split2("12345678")
res168: Array[String] = Array(12, 34, 56, 78)

scala> def split2(x:String):Array[String] = x.sliding(2,2).toArray
split2: (x: String)Array[String]

scala> split2("12345678")
res168: Array[String] = Array(12, 34, 56, 78)

scala> "12345678".sliding(4,4).toArray
res171: Array[String] = Array(1234, 5678)
```

Comment: rror: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : Symbol
[ERROR]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
[ERROR]     df.withColumn("newcol",explode(myudf_split2('col2))).select("col1","newcol").show
[ERROR]                                                 ^
[ERROR] one error found

i have scala 2.12.x and spark 1.6.x(working environment)

Comment: what is your df.schema?

Comment: spark 1.6 old.. I don't think it supports udf functions..please consider using spark 2.x versions

Comment: Sorry, couldn't able to do as we have CDH 5.14. parcel,if any
any alternative please suggest

Comment: this cloudera version might have spark 2.x.. you might be launching "spark-shell", pls try launching using "spark2-shell". Also in which step you are getting error? is it udf()?

Comment: Thanks 

Could able to achieve it with minor changes:

df.withColumn("newcol",explode(myudf_split2(df.col("col2")))).select("col1","newcol").show

Can you help me under stand what exactly happened in  
->split2**(x:String):Array[String]** and
-> split2**(_:String):Array[String]**

Comment: glad that it helped you.. I have added explanation. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

val df = Seq(("abc","2E2J2K2F"),("bcd","2K3D")).toDF("col1","col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string]

scala> def split2(x:String):Array[String] = x.sliding(2,2).toArray
split2: (x: String)Array[String]

scala> val myudf_split2 = udf ( split2(_:String):Array[String] )
myudf_split2: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.withColumn("newcol",explode(myudf_split2(df.col("col2")))).select("col1","newcol").show

+----+------+
|col1|newcol|
+----+------+
| abc|    2E|
| abc|    2J|
| abc|    2K|
| abc|    2F|
| bcd|    2K|
| bcd|    3D|
+----+------+